# Is there a Solr query parser that will parse out and create filter queries?

Tags: solr, dismax

I'm looking for a Solr query parser that can parse out and correctly apply filter queries, leaving anything not specified with a field as a general search term.

So:

```
tags:sql title:mysql recordset
```

This would do the following:

- Create a FilterQuery query for records with "sql" in the "tags" field
- Create a FilterQuery for records with "mysql" in the "title" field
- Create a normal query for records with "recordset" in the default field

Does such a query parser exist?

**Edit:** I've found that if I search for "*" as the query, and then do the "qf" param as this, it works:

```
tags:sql AND title:mysql AND recordset
```

What are the drawbacks to doing this?  I assume scoring would be all wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `fq` (filter query) instead of "qf"?

Comment: Why not form the Solr query you want at the client side? i.e. `fq=tags:sql&fq=title:mysql&q=recordset` before you fire off your query to Solr?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've ended up doing. I just wanted way, way finer-grained control over the query than any QueryParser was going to give me.